# Confused about CSS class naming convention

Tags: css, naming-conventions

Trying to learn CSS, I was writing code and wanted to name three CSS classes. I searched CSS name convention and stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927193/css-class-naming-convention/7927219#7927219). So I named my classes as suggested in the answer, but one of my installed atom packages is advising me against it. I am now confused if I am doing it right or not. for `<div class="container top">`I have:

```
.container.top {
  background-color: #e4f9ff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Again there are different use cases when to use only `.container` or `.top` or `.container.top` or `.container>.top` so keep reading you will get the information.

Comment: Please read the [CSSLint documentation](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-adjoining-classes). _“This rule is intended to flag uses of adjoining classes that will fail in Internet Explorer 6 and earlier.”_ — Yes, you’re doing it right; just disable that rule.

Comment: @user4642212 Thank you for the link. Then should I not use space between classes to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Gigili No, a space changes the meaning completely.

Answer (score 0):

`.container.top {}` targets a div with both classes (container & top)
If you put a space inbetween them `.container .top {}` then it targets the child with a class of (top) inside the partent (container).

Everything looks correct on my end. Unless it's not accomplishing what you want it to accomplish.

```css
.container.top {
  background-color: #e4f9ff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container top">
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the case of:**
CSS: `.container.top { color:red; }`(no space)
HTML: `<div class="container top">First text layer</div>`

"**ONLY in this case** where a div has `.container` and `.top` as classes then apply css"

An example of this would be the "Night mode" on most website... Devs apply a `.night` class to the body tag via JS.

On the CSS side you would have a regular `body` tag related color like so `body{ background-white; }` and a night mode only color `body.night{ background-color:black; }`.
As soon as the `.night` class is added to the `body`, the background color will change because it has priority as it's more "targeted".

/------/

**In the case of:** CSS: `.container, .top { color:red; }`
HTML: `<div class="container top">First text layer</div>`

"If there is a .container class apply css. if there is a .top class apply css"